# How to prove that the orthogonal projections of the given point on the sides of the quadrilateral are concyclic?

Tags: geometry

I have the following question with me:

"Let $ ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and let $ O \in AC \cap BD$, $ P \in AB \cap CD$, $ Q \in BC \cap DA$. If $ R$ is the orthogonal projection of $ O$ on the line $ PQ$ prove that the orthogonal projections of $ R$ on the sidelines of $ ABCD$ are concyclic."

And all I could do in this entire problem is figure out a few cyclic quadrilaterals and do simple angle chasing giving me no significant result.

Can anyone please help me with this question?

I also have a doubt in a particular notation in geometry, which says considering $ mod \pi $ and then mentions two sides like this $(EF,EH)$ and then writes the following statement:
Considering $mod \pi, $we have $(EH,EF)=(EG,EA)$(the sides,etc mentioned are just an example, no specific usage). What exactly does it mean?

Comment: This is problem n°1 in Romania Team Selection tests for I.M.Olympiads Timisoara Bucharest 2008 Day 4

Comment: @JeanMarie yupp I came to know, but didn't get any solutions